# Masking a 3-dimensional tensor of shape (x, y, z) with a 2-dimensional boolean mask of shape (x, y)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following tensor, `output` of shape (2, 6, 2):

```
[[[0.4 0.2]
  [0.7 0.5]
  [0.4 0.1]
  [0.5 0.4]
  [0.9 0.7]
  [0.2 0.9]]

 [[0.6 0.6]
  [0.3 0.5]
  [0.7 0.2]
  [0.8 0.1]
  [0.3 0.5]
  [0.4 0.7]]]
```

and have the following boolean mask tensor, `mask` of shape (2, 6):

```
mask = tf.sequence_mask(lengths=[3, 4] maxlen=6)

[[ True  True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]]
```

How can I use `mask` (or an adjustment of it) to apply `masked_output = tf.boolean_mask(output, masks)` resulting in the following:

```
[[[0.4 0.2]
  [0.7 0.5]
  [0.4 0.1]
  [0.0 0.0]
  [0.0 0.0]
  [0.0 0.0]]

 [[0.6 0.6]
  [0.3 0.5]
  [0.7 0.2]
  [0.8 0.1]
  [0.0 0.0]
  [0.0 0.0]]]
```

**EDIT**

The following changes, but it still seems like a messy way of doing it. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

```
mask = tf.sequence_mask(lengths=[[3, 3], [4, 4]] maxlen=6)
mask = tf.transpose(mask, [0, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most efficient way, but it works

```
flat_mask = tf.reshape(mask, shape=(-1,))
expanded_flat_mask = tf.tile(flat_mask, [2])
expanded_mask = tf.reshape(expanded_flat_mask, shape=(2, 6, 2))
masked_output = tf.boolean_mask(output, expanded_mask)
```

Or alternatively

```
masked_output = output * tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1), output.dtype)
```

Comment: That results in a (2, 6, 1) tensor, but `tf.boolean_mask(output, bigger_mask)` needs both to be (2, 6, 2)

Comment: You're right. See updated solution. I couldn't find a more direct way of doing this.

Comment: @KOB added an alternate solution as well that seems a bit simpler.